# Save polygon on map

Tags: python, polygon, folium, osmnx

It is probably a noob question but I'm still a beginner with maps and these libraries.

I used  OSMnx, NetworkX and GeoPandas the draw a map with two polygons on it.

Each polygon have the begin with a "main node" (I have only two) and then to two different nodes which should be at a specific location which is according to angle and distance from the main nodes.

I plotted the map with the two polygons and everything is fine but when I wanted to transfer it to Folium graph, there is nothing on it.

```
col = ['black','blue'] #colors for main nodes
col2 =['red','yellow'] #color for other nodes

fig, ax = ox.plot_graph(G, close=False, show=False)
for i in range(len(df)):
    lon = df.iloc[i]['LON']
    lat = df.iloc[i]['LAT']
    ax.scatter(lon, lat, c=col[i], s=80) #plot two main nodes

poly_l = []   #List of two polygon

for i in range(len(df)):
    clon = df.iloc[i]['LON']
    clat = df.iloc[i]['LAT']
    stopA = df.iloc[i]['endA'] 
    startA = df.iloc[i]['startA']
    loci = (clat,clon)
    rad = float(df.iloc[i]['radius'])
    loc2,loc3 = find_angles(loci,stopA,startA,rad) 
    loc = (loci[1],loci[0])
    poly = Polygon([loc,loc2,loc3])
    ax.scatter(loc2[0], loc2[1], c=col2[i], s=80)
    ax.scatter(loc3[0], loc3[1], c=col2[i], s=80)
    poly_l.append(poly)

for polygon in poly_l:
    patch = PolygonPatch(polygon, fc='green', ec='none', alpha=0.3, zorder=-1)
    ax.add_patch(patch)
plt.show()

graph_map = ox.plot_graph_folium(G, popup_attribute='name', edge_width=2)
graph_map.save('coordinates.html')
```

this is the map after `plt.show`

[image]

and this is the Folium map:

[image]

How can I save my plotting on my map?

Comment: Please provide a minimal, complete reproducible code snippet so we can reproduce what you are doing.